# How to use env var in `flinkConfiguration` of `FlinkDeployment`?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm deploying Flink into kubernetes using the Flink Kubernetes Operator. I have a `flinkDeployment` like so:

```
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  flinkVersion: "v1_15"
  flinkConfiguration:
    kubernetes.entry.path: "/opt/flink/goldsky-docker-entrypoint.sh"
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: "2"
  ...otherstuff
```

I want to configure the [statsd reporter](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/deployment/metric_reporters/#statsd) but I would like the host and port to be configured using an env var, similar to something like the following

```
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  flinkVersion: "v1_15"
  flinkConfiguration:
    kubernetes.entry.path: "/opt/flink/goldsky-docker-entrypoint.sh"
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: "2"
    metrics.reporter.stsd.factory.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.statsd.StatsDReporterFactory
    metrics.reporter.stsd.host: ENV_VAR_STATSD_HOST
    metrics.reporter.stsd.port: ENV_VAR_STATSD_PORT
    metrics.reporter.stsd.interval: 60 SECONDS
```

In particular, I want the host to be configured by a env var because it needs to be based on the IP address of the host that the flink pod runs on (I want to send statsd metrics to [vector](https://vector.dev/) which is running as a daemonset in my cluster). I can hardcode the statsd port if necessary but would also prefer to configure the port using env vars as well.

Is this possible? Can I use env vars when configuring Flink using the kubernetes operator? If so, how?

Comment: if you dont mind , can you share "goldsky-docker-entrypoint.sh " ? don't need entire script but how you are calling the original "docker-entrypoint.sh" from flink in your script ?